# cannot sort an array of objects according to objects' attribute value

Tags: c++, arrays, class, sorting, object

The class `Record` contains the month, day, and balance.
After creating the Record Object array, I would like to sort it by balance in ascending order and display them.
Then, I would like to sort it by the date in ascending order and display them again.
I was able to sort by balance, but cannot get the right order when sort by date.
My approach to sort by date is:

1. define a isGreater func to compare the value of month of objects `r1` and `r2`, return true if month r1<r2 else false, if month of r1 == month of r2, then compare their day.
2. in `sortByDate()`, implement bubble sort and the condition `isGreater(arr[j],arr[j+1])`
3. if the condition is true, then swap
   The expected output should be:

```
sorting according to balance:
9 14 -104.6
12 14 -104.5
12 13 -104.5

sorting according to date:
9 14 -104.6
12 13 -104.5
12 14 -104.5
```

Here is my code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Record {
private:
    int month, day;
    double balance;

public:
    void set(int m, int d, double b) { month = m; day = d; balance = b; }
    int getMonth() { return month; }
    int getDay() { return day; }
    double getBalance() { return balance; }
};




bool isGreater(Record r1, Record r2)
{
    if (r1.getMonth() > r2.getMonth())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (r1.getMonth() < r2.getMonth())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (r1.getDay() > r2.getDay())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}


void sortByBalance(Record arr[], int n)
{
    int i, j;
    Record temp;
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j].getBalance() > arr[j + 1].getBalance())
            {
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void sortByDate(Record arr[], int n)
{
    int i, j;
    Record temp;
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
        {
            if (isGreater(arr[j], arr[j+1])); //{4.20, 3.15, 5.21, 6.21, 6.20}
            {
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void printArr(Record arr[], int n)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        cout << arr[j].getMonth() << ' ' << arr[j].getDay() << ' ' << arr[j].getBalance() << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Record arr[30];
    int n;
    cout << "Enter the number of the records:" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    cout << "Enter the contents of each records:" << endl;
    int m, d;
    double b;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> m >> d >> b;
        arr[i].set(m, d, b);
    }

    cout << "Sort according to the balance:" << endl;
    sortByBalance(arr, n);
    printArr(arr, n);

    cout << "Sort according to the time:" << endl;
    sortByDate(arr, n);
    printArr(arr, n);   

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you built this with compiler warnings turned on and paid attention to them, you would have noticed the stray semicolon at the end of the line

```
 if (isGreater(arr[j], arr[j+1]));
```

which effectively disables that check and just performs the swap regardless.

(That said, you should be using `std::sort` instead of writing your own bubblesort anyway.)

Comment: Thank you! It is sorting by date in the right order now.
I did not notice that semicolon at all!
I will pay attention to the warning from now on :D